# How can I determine the cause of an IIS7 memory leak?

Tags: iis-7, memory-leak

I have an IIS7 website which is live right now. If I watch memory usage in the remote server its usually about 300-400mb however sometimes randomly it goes up to 10gb within 5-10 seconds. I have tried to replicate this error in my localhost by sending the same requests from the server iislog in an even shorter time period, but I can't replicate it. I've checked my code for not disposed objects etc. and my code seems safe.

I've tried serving this website on IIS6, fw2 and result was always the same. I've installed .NET Memory Profiler on the server and took a snapshot while this leak was happening, and it lists a huge amount of memory in the unreferenced objects part. How can I see the cause?

Comment: where are the ms gurus : )

Comment: Hi, is the problem resolved? What are the steps you performed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IIS Debug Diagnostics tool: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=24370

Also, within IIS you may want to look over the properties for your application pools. Specifically, try modifying your Recycling intervals or manually recycling.

Do you have increased memory when users try to upload?

Comment: Yes, there are increase in memory when user tries to upload data.